# kotlin call function with android view

Tags: android, function, kotlin

We are trying to understand calling a function in Kotlin

The function looks like this

```
    fun onSIMPLE(view: View){
    val snack = Snackbar.make(view,"This is a simple Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
    snack.show()
}
```

And the call is made this way

```
btnSB2.setOnClickListener {onSIMPLE(it)}
```

What we do not understand is how does one know to use the keyword **"it"**?
Who ever created the keyword "it" must have never searched the Web

We plugged every reasonable keyword in the ( ) to solve the issue
YES we also looked at the documentation
Is there a better way to construct the function or make the call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`it` is the implicit name for a single parameter lambda. You can override as you wish, e.g:

```
btnSB2.setOnClickListener { view -> onSIMPLE(view)}
```

Comment: So we needed to look at the documentation for lambda's when calling a function. Even though the keyword "it" works we assume this to be non favorable syntax ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

`setOnClickListener` expects a lambda as a parameter, using a Java-like approach, this should look like this:

```
btnSB2.setOnClickListener({
    v:View -> onSIMPLE(it)
})
```

Also, if the lambda is the last parameter for a given function, it can be specified outside of the parenthesis, which would look like this:

```
btnSB2.setOnClickListener {
    v:View -> onSIMPLE(it)
}
```

It is common for lambda functions to have a single parameter. For these functions, Kotlin maintains the `it` keyword. Knowing this, the code becomes:

```
btnSB2.setOnClickListener {
    onSIMPLE(it)
}
```

Comment: To use your first two answers we needed to use this declarationclass MainActivity(val it: View) : AppCompatActivity() { The concept makes the code a little confusing